# Creating a slicing tree in R

Tags: r, tree, nodes, slice, cran

Does anyone know if there is a package or simple way in R to create tree structures of the following form:

[image]

I am not looking for a way to create a nice plot like above. My biggest problem is finding a way to work with such a tree where there is a clear distinction between nodes, leaves and children-nodes. For example I would like to be able to switch two leaves by adjusting a string or vector. So I guess this is mostly a 'data storage' problem.

I have been looking for quite some time now and stumbled upon a package called 'Dendrogram'. The problem with this package is that (as far as I know) it does not allow the labelling of inner nodes such as 'H'and 'V'. Only the final leaves can carry a value or string.

Another package I found is 'rpart' but I think these are only useful for regression trees.

If anyone knows something I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi I should add that since you are new here you might want to read [**the about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made **much** more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem, you accept it by clicking the little check mark. You are under absolutely **no** obligation to do so, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an edgelist you can do something very simillar with with igraph:

```
el <- matrix( c( "H" , "V" , "H" , "V2" , "V" , "1" , "V" , "V3" , "V3" , "3" , "V3" , "4" , "V2" , "2" , "V2" , "H2" ) , ncol = 2 , byrow = TRUE )
g <- graph.edgelist(el , directed = TRUE )
V(g)$label <- get.vertex.attribute(g, 'name')
plot(g,layout=layout.reingold.tilford)
```

You can also name you nodes in the `el` command as letters and then use `get.vertex.attribute(g, 'name')` to see what the resulting nodes are called, and then pass whatever character vector you like to get your labels as they are in the picture.
[image]

Comment: Can you upload to the web and paste a link of what you get? (I realise you don't have the rep yet to include pics). Try using [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/). Do you get any error messages at all? Can you also paste the output from `sessionInfo()` into your code block in your question then we can try and work out why it is different.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this looks very promising! 
I have one problem though. When I simply copy the code you provided above R creates a graph that looks quite different. Setting the attribute directed = FALSE improves the graph a bit but it is still a lot different:

http://s22.postimg.org/uwzzrggj5/Trees.png

According to the igraph site the Reingold Tilford layout should do the trick but for some reason it is not creating the graph from the top down in a correct way.

Comment: SessionInfo() gives the following output:
R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] igraph_0.6.5-1

Comment: @user2215428 I was using an old version of `igraph`. When I updated I encountered the same problem as you. Seems the pacakge authors updated the method you need. use `graph.edgelist` instead of `graph.data.frame`. BTW to include code in comments (or inline instead of in a code block) surround the code with back ticks ` So mean() surrounded by back ticks will become `mean()`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem for me. I get the same 'flat' graph as before with a slightly different order of nodes. Just updated R to the latest version but this did not help either.

Comment: @Arno Yikes. It seems this is a known bug. See [***here***](https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/1154105). I recommend to download an old version of the source code. Such as [**igraph_0.6-2**](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph/igraph_0.6-2.tar.gz), then install from source. You can do this on the command line by opening  up a `CMD` prompt and typing `R CMD INSTALL path/to/downloaded/file.tar.gz`. Then reopen R and run the code. Let me know if this works.

Comment: The install from source failed, but I managed to find an old binary package and now I am able to create the same graph as above! Thank you very much for all your help :-).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rpart may not suit your need. Try [phylobase](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phylobase/index.html) package.

If your tree can be read from a file then you could probably use some kind of XML tree parser like [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XiMpLe/index.html).